# how to load images in web page fast with preloading and show activity indicator while images are loading

Tags: javascript, html

I have web page i want that image should laod fast using preloader and it show activity indicator i have searched but not getting right thing for this is there any simple way to do this thanks

Comment: show some code you've already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can preload images using javascript/jquery.
What you need to do is create a 'img' with 'src' from javascript and at it to the DOM.

You 'll find more info here: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/preload-images-with-jquery.html

Comment: yes i have done this i also googled this but my loader has some problems